# Как достать подмассив из массива объектов?

Tags: javascript, массивы

Есть вот такой массив объектов, в котором лежит массив orders,  нужно получить orders и вывести новый массив который будет содержать то что лежит в массиве orders.

```
const users = [
    {
        name: "Oleg Petko",
        location: "Odesa",
        orders: [
            {
                item_name: "tomato",
                price: 10,
                quantity: 23
            },
            {
                item_name: "potato",
                price: 5,
                quantity: 6
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "Vlad Diachenko",
        location: "Odesa",
        orders: [
            {
                item_name: "cigarets",
                price: 65,
                quantity: 10
            },
            {
                item_name: "potato",
                price: 5,
                quantity: 1
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "Sergey Diachenko",
        location: "Oleshki",
        orders: [
            {
                item_name: "cigarets",
                price: 56,
                quantity: 5
            },
            {
                item_name: "tomato",
                price: 25,
                quantity: 11
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "Roman Makarenko",
        location: "Oleshki",
        orders: [
            {
                item_name: "cigarets",
                price: 76,
                quantity: 2
            },
            {
                item_name: "condoms",
                price: 120,
                quantity: 2
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "Vlad Timoshenko",
        location: "Oleshki",
        orders: [
            {
                item_name: "tomato",
                price: 34,
                quantity: 2
            },
            {
                item_name: "powder",
                price: 56,
                quantity: 4
            },
        ]
    }
]

let orderArray = [];

for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++){
    
    let currOrd = users[i];
    if (currOrd == [orders]) {
        currOrd.push(orderArray)
    }
}

console.log(orderArray);
```

Comment: Возвращаемый массив должен просто содержать результаты перемножения свойств price и quantity?

Comment: Простите, сейчас изменю вопрос, нужно вывести просто новый массив который будет содержать то что лежит в массиве orders.

Comment: То есть вы хотите на выходе получить массив который будет содержать массивы orders?

Comment: Абсолютно верно!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если на выходе нужен массив с массивами orders, то можно сделать таким образом

```
const users = [
    {
        name: 'Oleg Petko',
        location: 'Odesa',
        orders: [
            {
                item_name: 'tomato',
                price: 10,
                quantity: 23,
            },
            {
                item_name: 'potato',
                price: 5,
                quantity: 6,
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        name: 'Vlad Diachenko',
        location: 'Odesa',
        orders: [
            {
                item_name: 'cigarets',
                price: 65,
                quantity: 10,
            },
            {
                item_name: 'potato',
                price: 5,
                quantity: 1,
            },
        ],
    },
];

const arrOfOrders = users.map(({ orders }) => orders);

console.log(arrOfOrders);
```

Выход будет такой

```
[
  [
    { item_name: 'tomato', price: 10, quantity: 23 },
    { item_name: 'potato', price: 5, quantity: 6 }
  ],
  [
    { item_name: 'cigarets', price: 65, quantity: 10 },
    { item_name: 'potato', price: 5, quantity: 1 }
  ]
]
```

**UPD**

Так как по сути изменять исходные значения на лету не нужно, то думаю логически вернее будет `reduce()`

Тогда можно сделать так:

```
const arrOfOrders = users.reduce((acc, item) => {
    acc.push(item.orders);
    return acc;
}, []);
```

На выходе получиться тоже самое:

```
[
  [
    { item_name: 'tomato', price: 10, quantity: 23 },
    { item_name: 'potato', price: 5, quantity: 6 }
  ],
  [
    { item_name: 'cigarets', price: 65, quantity: 10 },
    { item_name: 'potato', price: 5, quantity: 1 }
  ]
]
```

Или можно сделать так:

```
const arrOfOrders = users.reduce((acc, item) => {
    return [...acc,...item.orders];
}, []);
```

Тогда на выходе мы получим массив объектов:

```
[
  { item_name: 'tomato', price: 10, quantity: 23 },
  { item_name: 'potato', price: 5, quantity: 6 },
  { item_name: 'cigarets', price: 65, quantity: 10 },
  { item_name: 'potato', price: 5, quantity: 1 }
]
```

Comment: Спасибо, выручили!